# How-to Giving Loading bar during copy process in php

Tags: php, copy, loading

This is my script:

```
function copyr($source, $dest) {
  // Simple copy for a file
  if (is_file($source)) {
    return copy($source, $dest);
  }
  // Make destination directory
  if (!is_dir($dest)) {
    mkdir($dest);
  }
  // If the source is a symlink
  if (is_link($source)) {
    $link_dest = readlink($source);
    return symlink($link_dest, $dest);
  }
  // Loop through the folder
  $dir = dir($source);
  while (false !== $entry = $dir -> read()) {
    // Skip pointers
    if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
      continue;
    }
    // Deep copy directories
    if ($dest !== "$source/$entry") {
      copyr("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry");
    }
  }
  // Clean up
  $dir -> close();
  return true;
}
```

And I call function like this:

```
<?php copyr("D:/ahmad","E:"); ?>
```

When I call the function `copyr` always loading pages long.
And how to display the loading bar when the copy process?

Comment: You wouldn't do this in just php. You might be able to use something like uploadify - http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: thank you, but how do I use it?

Comment: Uploadify should be well documented. look at this page, which includes sample code as well as a video demonstration: http://www.uploadify.com/demos/